# Mobile web interface for review

Tags: feature-request, review, mobile-web

I frequently find myself on the bus or train with time to review some edits, first time posts, etc.

However, it's not possible to do this on the mobile interface, and the desktop interface is very cumbersome to use on my phone. The modal dialogs slide around, I sometimes hit the wrong button, and the screen zooms halfway across the page when a text box gets focus.

I've seen other questions requesting a general mobile app, and the ability to close / flag posts on mobile, but nothing about reviewing on mobile.

When it's convenient for me to do, I don't always have my laptop, so I'd like to request a mobile interface for review.

Comment: Sounds like this will happen at some point, but not soon

Comment: I know this is old looking at submission date. But doesn't look like it was ever addressed. This feature would be awesome like Aaron originally stated.